# When someone gives you -2 points

Tags: support, down-votes

How to find the reason for someone giving you a -2 for a previously answered question that had been given 10 points?

Comment: As Ron Gordon once told me, *Leave the downvoters to stew in the toxic goulash of their own making*. You may politely ask for the reason behind an apparently nonsensical downvote, but the downvoter is not compelled to provide it. The reputation system stands on anonimity, and you are simply staring at the bad side of it. Just look at the other way.

Comment: Thanks, Makes sense.

Comment: @Jack: I was told recently that goulash gets better every time it is reheated. What does it mean for downvoters, then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: toxic goulash gets more toxic every time is it reheated, so the metaphor is probably suggesting not to lose sleep over downvotes, before it becomes a major problem :)

Comment: I would add that altruistic users like you (who provide a huge number of answers) need to consider that maybe a downvote can be the inclemency of the statistics. That I am saying is that maybe was a upvote, or merely some user downvoting your answer from a huge number of users who read your answers. If you can not understand a negative vote, or a negative comment, note that you are exposed to statistics, even when you answer was perfectly right. Many thanks for your answers in this site. Isn't required a response of this comment.

Comment: @Jack Sorry but what are you talking about? Surely you cannot endorse the statement "Leave the downvoters (to) stew in the toxic goulash of their own making" with no qualification? Equating every downvote to a "toxic goulash of the downvoter's own making" is a sure way to destroy the equilibrium the whole site is based upon. This is frightening...

Comment: @Did: Let me be clear: I did not equate *every* downvote to a bad thing. I simply sympathized with the OP about the fact that nonsensical downvotes *happen*, and there is little to do about them, except to focus on the positive side of *sharing the knowledge*.

Comment: @Jack I'd answer "Leave the upvoters and rep whores to stew in the toxic goulash of their own making."

Comment: @Jack Not good to overgeneralize;  get the picture now?

Comment: @amWhy: I got it before, too, I am just sorry my words were misinterpreted, I hope to have shed some light on them with my previous comment.

Comment: Dear asker of this question.  Get used to it.  It happens.  One answer upvote: 10 pts. one answer downvote -2.  So you gained 8 points for your answer.  Get used to receiving downvotes if you plan to continue answering.  I get an occasion  downvote on questions of ten or more upvotes, from 2013!  Should I post to meta every time an upvoted answer of mine, which I  posted a few months, or a year, or three years or five years ago, gets a downvote?  What if everyone posted to meta each and every time they received a single downvote they don't understand?

Comment: @amWhy I agree with your advice to the OP. But, "rep whores" - really?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Search for "help vampires and rep whores" on Meta.SE, or on this site.  I rarely rarely use such terms, and it's not the best choice; but it's had uptake on SE for a very long time.

Comment: @amWhy I think that is a real problem downvotes to users who think that his/her answer was right, (or those who don't receive a positive exchange as answer accepted, a comment appreciating the work, an upvote), because my belief is that this site stands on altruism. The reputation for each user means a different thing. What is the meaning of a downvote (-2)? Seems few, but it maybe can have pernicious consequences. From my viewpoint has no importance, with exception of malicious votes. And I believe that in the world of mathematicians, we want to put a logic even in colloquial discussions,

Comment: @user243301 I don't think I've said anything contrary to that.  But you also need to realize that there are too many non-altruistic answers as well.  Answering a question $\not\equiv$ being altruistic.  And some downvoters and/or closers are motivated by sheer altruism, to keep this site useful, and sound, by simply being janitors.  So, I don't like over-generalizations, that's all.  And what you say does nothing to challenge what I said when I addressed the asker.  What I get is why haters-of-downvotes don't also argue against  unwarrented upvotes?  That's the bigger problem, on this site!

Comment: @user243301 I enjoy your idealism, which I shared on this site for close to four years; I still retain much of it, but I've also seen too much abuse of the site.  Some answerers are playing a game ...  answering as much and as often as they can ***in order to gain rep***.  There's nothing wrong with such a thing when it's legitimately accompanied by the altruistic desire for askers to learn, and learn how to work independently.  Some chronic answerers actually enable students to **not** study, to not practice, so that askers cannot pride in what they do.  So I'd hardly call enablers atruistic.

Comment: Oh, and re: the problem you mention in your last post:  your welcome to visit my answers and upvote some of them, out of a sense of justice for all the torment I've suffered from having received downvotes over the past 6.5 years, most of which were correct!  Whaaah.... Maybe I'll post a complaint to meta too!.

Comment: No, @user243301  I'm not talking about "hate" here;  simply different perspectives, most all of which are valid.  Disagreement $\neq$ hate.  Down-vote $\neq$ hate.  And what about most users, who both upvote and downvote, who close some questions, but vote to reopen others.  You're making a false dichotomy.

Comment: Then I'm sorry @amWhy , my comment was about your expression *haters-of-downvotes*. English is not my native language and thus I have misinterpreted this expression.

Comment: To the asker of this question.  I'm surprised you haven't linked the answer that recently received only one downvote, and that previously and earned you only one upvote.  Without reference, this question is far too broad.

Comment: Since I misinterpreted your words @amWhy , feel free to require me to delete the mentioned comment or flag it.

Comment: @user243301 I have not flagged, and I do not feel free to require anything from you here. You are free to delete your own comment, if you choose, or to keep it.  I'm not angry or offended.  We all misinterpret another, here and there, and I'm sure I'm no exception.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience and I'm sorry by my comment. I've considered delete my comment @amWhy

Comment: see here math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/27243/revisions

Comment: @GuyFsone Could you be a little bit more specific as to how that relates to the question here?

Comment: Even if upvotes & downvotes had the same magnitude, they are entirely different beasts, not merely a sign difference. This is an artefact of our human reward system, an upvote is an affirmation whereas a downvote carries the notion that something is wrong and needs action.

Comment: On the other hand, this site is not research level. The idea is to exchange ideas and offer help to students of the subject. I know several people who won't post to this site because of the snark and downvoting. I think commenters should be required to give a reason for their downvotes, even if provided anonymously.

Comment: @Did: I made that comment to Jack in the context of a serial downvoting episode he was experiencing.  I think all of us who have been through a spate of random downvotes for the first time tend to get down about it, and Jack wrote a post expressing that.  I just used some colorful language to tell him that there are a lot of people here who are motivated for a bunch of terrible reasons to vote negatively, and the only way to get back at such people is to let them be their terrible selves.  I did not mean to imply that all people who downvote are terrible, or that they are goulash.

Comment: @RonGordon Duly noted, then you forgot the crucial qualification "serial" in your comment. Actually the whole comment by Jack, not only the part that is quoting you (apparently, out of context), expresses a very precise point of view on downvotes, which, while in line with their past activity on the site, I find highly disturbing. How to understand "you are simply staring at the bad side of it. Just look at the other way" if not as a general, a priori, disqualification of downvotes? How do we know that user348749 is "staring at the bad side" of the rep system? How do we know ...

Comment: ... that the downvote mentioned here was "nonsensical"? Simply because the user received a downvote "for a previously answered question that had been" upvoted? Don't make me laugh... Why summon the notion of "nonsense" at all in the first place? Sorry but it should be obvious to every mature user of the site, and even more so to a mod, that **downvotes are not a bad side of the site** but a crucial element of the principles the SE sites are built upon.

Comment: @Did: I agree and have made this point before: downvotes are not only not bad, they are crucial to this site's success.  And the downvote the OP got may or may not have been made with good intentions, I cannot know.  That said, if the OP has checked and checked his/her result, then the only thing to do is, as Jack said, ask for a reason in the comments.  Failing that (and generally speaking, that is what happens 99.9% of the time), then the OP should just move on.  Or maybe ask if there is anything about the post that could be clearer.

Comment: @RonGordon Amen to that. :-)

Answer (score 22):

I pose a frame challenge.

*Nobody* gave you +10 points, nor did they give you -2 points. What happened is that people used the ratings system built into the site. This is not dissimilar from other sites with user-generated content that ask users to rate content.

The *site* used those ratings to give you +10 points in an effort to encourage the kind of content people want to see, and also to give you -2 points in an effort to discourage the kind of content people don't wan't to see.

The question you mean to ask is:

> Why did one person dislike a post that another person liked?

and you can hopefully recognize the futility of posing it as an abstract question.

Comment: This. So much this. Votes are not like grades in an exam.

Answer (score 10):

Any user with 15 points can vote up on any question or answer they want, and any user with 125 points can vote down on any question or answer they want.  The default is that no reason is given.  To communicate specific feedback on the post a comment would be used instead. The voting provides a sort of rating system, inevitably with a lot of noise, but on the whole appears to be useful, especially if more people vote more often.

Want more upvotes on the site?  You can do your part by voting up more on useful posts.  As for our own posts, we are unfortunately psychologically programmed to be affected even by the noise, but votes are not necessarily even intended to communicate anything to the poster, but rather are a user's use of their rating privilege on the site.

See also [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often/1613#1613) (and the question it answers).

Answer (score 5):

You can take odd mystery downvotes as an opportunity to re-read your answer and see if it can be improved.

If no improvements are obvious, you could assume it was a slip of the mouse, and forget it.

Comment: Adopting this particular attitude improved my feelings about undeserved (at least IMO) downvotes a lot. Not my fault that the downvoter was either careless or ignorant.

Answer (score 3):

The other part of the question is +10 vs -2.  Each downvote decreases your rep by 2, but upvotes increase your rep by 10.

Comment: I think the reason for is the *shock* of one or two downvotes on their own will encourage people to improve a bad post, but they don't mean much when mixed in with $10$ upvotes.

Comment: @TobyMak: 10 points, 1 upvote, was referred to I think.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $10$ points for one upvote. Even though the downvotes don't reduce your reputation by that much, the score still shocks people with a bad post enough to change their post.